# Default language changed in parts of admin backend

Tags: localisation

My default backend language is German. This week I've noticed that some texts in the backend changed language to English. For example:

[image]

Language dropdown in the footer is set to German. I've been developing a module but haven't changed any translation files. The module is now disabled - the problem still persists.

Do you know what happened or can advise how to investigate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a translation file in one module that was declared as `Mage_Adminhtml` in the xml file. After changing it to `Groupname_Modulename` translations worked again.